# Hosting a webpage on github

Tags: reactjs, github, https, hosting, domain-name

i'm trying to host a website on github and it keeps showing this error :

> `"Unavailable for your site because your domain is not properly configured to support HTTPS(coursera-confusion.com) — Troubleshooting custom domains  HTTPS provides a layer of encryption that prevents others from snooping on or tampering with traffic to your site. When HTTPS is enforced, your site will only be served over HTTPS. Learn more. "`

this is my first time hosting a web repo on github.please help.

Comment: Sometimes it takes a bit of time for the certificate to be issued. Try waiting a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using github to deploy your website**

The deploying process is the following:
(Try to use **VSCode**)

Consider that your files are present inside the 'project' folder

*i)* Create a new folder 'build' inside your main 'project' folder.

*ii)* Move your website data in 'built' folder. Inside the 'build' folder all your website data will be present.(images, index.html , .css, .js, or any reactjs files)

*iii)* Traverse to the main 'project' folder through cmd and type '**npm init**' command in VsCode Terminal to initialize pacakge.json file inside your main 'project' folder.(Ensure that Node.js is installed before using node package manager(npm))

*iv)* Go to package.json file and use **npm i gh-pages** command to install gh-pages, which will be added as a dependancy in package.json file.

*v)* Your github repo link is present as value of homepage key in package.json file.
    homepage : "https://github.com/username/project"

*vi)* Create a script 
    Replace "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"', 
    with "deploy" : "gh-pages -d build"

*vii)* Push all this to github (Add .gitignore file so that node modules are not pushed to github)

git init

git add .

git commit -m "deploy"

git remote add project "https://username.github.io/project"

git push -u project master

*viii)* Through cmd run your project now by using this command
    **npm run deploy**  (Should display "Published" after you run the project)

*ix)* Go to Github repo that you have created for your project and check, there must be a new branch 'gh-pages' added with your master branch.

*x)* Now from the settings of your repository, select **gh-pages** branch as the source of your github pages.

And finally, your site is ready to be published at https://username.github.io/project/. 
Wait for 5-10 mins and then check it.